# On a server I run, bogus incoming mail for a username which is my name. Should I be worried?

Tags: email-spoofing, identity-theft

A server I run has a minimal public-facing mail exposure, running postfix on port 25 (no authentication on this port; IMAP is accessible by other means). In my mail logs it is not uncommon to find 'bogus' mail destined for non-existent users, which is usually spam. However recently I have noticed that a host attempted to deliver mail to a username which is my name. It happened recently, and then about a week prior, both from addresses in India.

Administratively, this server is not even owned under my name (i.e. the account details we have with the provider are not mine). There is nothing about the server that has anything to do with me other than a website which resides on the server, which is the personal website of someone I know; and that website itself has nothing to do with me either. In any case, my name never appears 'anywhere on the server', whether on a website or otherwise.

This is reminiscent of 'deep advert' networks where you'll suddenly see advertisements for a mattress on Facebook after you've searched 'Mattress Giant' on Google maps, or something. But the present situation is a little different and I was wondering what the likely explanations could be, and whether it's an indication that maybe some of my personal information has been compromised.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the description you've provided. But unless you have a very rare name it might be created by accident from variations over dictionaries, i.e. you get 1000s of mails with an invalid recipient name and then there is one which actually exists - pure luck.

Comment: Good point. Thing is we don't get a whole lot of this bogus mail, I'd say it's not uncommon but not voluminous. And the only such spam we've received for recipients in the name of a person (as opposed to 'webmaster' or 'admin' or something) has been my name and the name associated with owner of the personal site (he doesn't use his first name for his email on the site, it's something more generic like 'hello@'). On top of that, my name is pretty rare.

Comment: In this case check where you have used this email address, i.e. who you have send mail using this address. The recipient might have given away the mail to somebody else (like shops often do) or the recipients account might have been compromised (also often with shops).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the address does not exist, which is why it appears in the logs as a failed receipt.